# Scraping a table using R (rvest)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Trying to scrape a table with the following code (Link to website in code):

```
zb <- read_html("https://zigbeealliance.org/classic-product-search/")
zb %>%
html_nodes("tr.field_1") %>%
  html_text()
```

I am basically trying to scrape fields from the tables in the page and combine to a master table. But I failed scraping whole tables or field by field. Similar code is working for other websites.

Many thanks

Comment: That data is dynamically retrieved from https://us-east-1-renderer-read.knack.com/v1/scenes/scene_19/views/view_30/records?callback=jQuery17205643217545234003_1629841479196&format=both&page=1&rows_per_page=25&sort_field=field_17&sort_order=desc&filters=%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22field_1%22%2C%22operator%22%3A%22is+not+blank%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22All+Zigbee+Certified+Products%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D&_=1629841479481  which can be found in network tab of browser when loading page. Looks like the request needs specific header(s)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `rvest` package won't help you much here.  First, though not fatal, is that the table isn't actually a table.  Each item in the table is in an element of class `kn-list-item-container`, so theoretically, you could get all of these nodes and that would do it.  However, the table is generated with a javascript call which hasn't loaded when the page reads, so the table is not actually "there" in the code.

```
> zb %>% html_nodes(".kn-list-item-container")
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

You might be better off with `RSelenium`.  Here's a [link to a tutorial](https://thatdatatho.com/tutorial-web-scraping-rselenium/)

Answer (score 0):

Scraped the first 10 "pages", change it to whatever in the `map_dfr` fucntion

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

get_products <- function(page_number) {
  page <-
    paste0("https://csa-iot.org/csa-iot_products/page/", page_number, "/") %>%
    request() %>%
    req_perform() %>%
    resp_body_html()
  
  tibble(
    company = page %>%
      html_elements(".entry-company") %>%
      html_text2(),
    title = page %>%
      html_elements(".entry-title") %>%
      html_text2(),
    category = page %>%
      html_elements(".entry-category") %>%
      html_text2(),
    excerpt = page %>%
      html_elements(".entry-excerpt") %>%
      html_text2()
  )
}

df <- map_dfr(1:10, get_products)

# A tibble: 120 × 4
   company                              title               category excerpt
   <chr>                                <chr>               <chr>    <chr>  
 1 Lidl Stiftung & Co. KG               Lidl Home Smart Pl… Zigbee … Smart …
 2 Lidl Stiftung & Co. KG               Lidl Home Smart Pl… Zigbee … Smart …
 3 Lidl Stiftung & Co. KG               Lidl Home Smart Pl… Zigbee … Smart …
 4 Lidl Stiftung & Co. KG               Lidl Home Smart Pl… Zigbee … Smart …
 5 IMHOTEP CREATION                     EFLUID – NEOMITIS   Zigbee … EFLUID…
 6 Datek Smart Home AS                  Eva Door/Window Se… Zigbee … Eva Do…
 7 Tuya Global Inc.                     Panel light         Zigbee … SMART …
 8 Overkiz SAS                          TaHoma Din-Rail     Zigbee … Easy t…
 9 Overkiz SAS                          Kizconnect Din Rail Zigbee … Easy t…
10 Kee Tat Manufactory Holdings Limited Lidl Home Smart Pl… Zigbee … Smart …
# … with 110 more rows
```